# How to derive the Doppler shift of $v/c$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, doppler-effect

I tried to arrive at the formula for the Doppler shift of light:

$$ \frac{\Delta \lambda}{\lambda _{0}}=\frac{v}{c}$$

starting with the formula for doppler shift of wavelength

$$\lambda  = \lambda _{0}\sqrt{\frac{1-\frac{v}{c}}{1+\frac{v}{c}}}$$

for blueshift $\Delta \lambda = \lambda _{0} - \lambda$

$$\frac{\lambda _{0} - \lambda}{\lambda _{0}} = 1- \frac{\lambda} {\lambda _{0}} = 1 - \sqrt{\frac{1-\frac{v}{c}}{1+\frac{v}{c}}}.$$

Then I tried to approximate the formula by using binomial expansion on the square-root terms, but I couldn't arrive at $\frac{v}{c}$.

So how can it be derived?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically done from here.

Just rewrite $\frac{\sqrt{1 - v/c}}{\sqrt{1 + v/c}}$ as $(1 - v/c)^{1/2}(1 + v/c)^{-1/2}$, then use $(1+x)^{\alpha} = 1 + \alpha x + o(x^2)$ and *voila!*

You should get $(1 - v/c)^{1/2}(1 + v/c)^{-1/2} \approx (1 - \frac{1}{2}\frac{v}{c})(1 + \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right) \frac{v}{c}) \approx 1 - \frac{v}{c}$

Comment: Or you could say
$$\sqrt {\frac{1-v/c}{1+v/c}}=\frac{1-v/c}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$$ 

You can then ignore the denominator (put it equal to 1) because it has no term in /.
In fact the right hand expression is arguably more basic than the left hand one, as the numerator is the uncorrected Doppler shift and the denominator is the correction for time dilation between reference frames of source and observer – a negligible correction if $v<<c$.